# Pages without application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing my first ruby on rails web application at the moment and I have a little bit of a problem. I would need two pages (a start page and a login page) which haven't the `application.html.erb` layout.

At the moment I gained that by adding:

```
layout false
```

To my `login_controller.rb` file. But now I am unable to use the twitter bootstrap components which i included in the /assets/stylesheet and /assets/javascripts folder.

Can someone show me a best practice method how to add pages without the layouts and design from the `application.html.erb`, but still can use the twitter bootstrap components?

Comment: here's a good place to start: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html - when you're finished reading that, search for 'different layout [rails]' on stack overflow and you'll find a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a different layout file including only the assets you need.
A typical scenario I usually face is the administration section of a web site where the layout changes from the public section.

In that case you can create a layout `views/layouts/admin.htm.erb` like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Admin</title>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin", :media => "all" %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "admin" %>
          <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        </head>
        <body>
            <%= yield %>
        </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see there are two different manifest files for the js and css assets. 
That means there are two files:
`/assets/javascripts/admin.js` 
`/assets/stylesheets/admin.css`

Like in the `application.js` and `application.css` you can require bootstrap and other assets you may need for that specific layout.

**Here an example:**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_self
 */
```

**The last thing**

You need to tell rails to precompile the new manifest files you created.

In `/config/environments/production.rb`

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js.erb, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
 # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
 config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.css admin.js )
```

**NOW YOU CAN USE THE LAYOUT**

In your controller:

```
layout "admin"
```